# Remove unused imports from java project using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, import

How can we remove unused imports present in a java project using a Gradle task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we can use the spotless Gradle task to achieve this:

```
spotless {
  java {
    importOrder 'java', 'javax', 'org', 'com', 'com.diffplug', ''   // A sequence of package names

    removeUnusedImports() // removes any unused imports

    eclipse().configFile 'spotless.eclipseformat.xml'   // XML file dumped out by the Eclipse formatter
  }
}
```

we can also specify the import order for the project.

for additional information refer: https://github.com/diffplug/spotless

Comment: Is there a way to configure InteliJ code format XML instead of eclipse code format XML in eclipse().configFile

Comment: @OTUser you can change it to
intellij().configFile 'spotless.intellijformat.xml'   // XML file containing IntelliJ code format settings

Comment: This will use the settings defined in spotless.intellijformat.xml for formatting Java code instead of using Eclipse formatting settings. Make sure to create or specify the correct file containing your IntelliJ code format settings.

Comment: I see that `com.diffplug.gradle.spotless.JavaExtension` class has `eclipse()` but it doesn't have `intellij()`am getting below compiler error
`Could not find method intellij() for arguments [] on object of type com.diffplug.gradle.spotless.JavaExtension.`

Comment: can you share the complete spotless configuration that you are using?