# How to configure gradle spotless pugin to replace .* imports and sort fields and methods in Intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, spotless

I am using Java 17 with IntelliJ 2023.2.2 and attempting to configure the Gradle Spotless plugin to replace

```
import java.util.*
```

with individual class imports, such as

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
```

The post I found [Remove unused imports from java project using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61250522/remove-unused-imports-from-java-project-using-gradle) suggests using an external Eclipse config to handle this, but since I only use IntelliJ and not Eclipse, I wonder if it's possible to configure IntelliJ's code style XML to replace the .* imports. Additionally, I would like the Spotless plugin to sort the fields and methods by name. Is this possible?

I have tried various configurations, but none of them worked.

Comment: That seems like a job for an IDE, not a build system.

Comment: Is  Idea `Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Imports -> Use single class import` config useful for handling this issue